# Video conversion with php ffmpeg not playable on browser

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, h.264

I'm using the PHP FFMPEG Library https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg on a web application to convert some videos uploaded by the users in different formats to MP4 H264 video format, playable on most browsers.

I have a problem with some MP4 videos with an specific codec, this videos are being converted succesfully with PHP FFMPEG but are not playable on the browser.

- Type: Vídeo
- Codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (H264)
- Resolution: 320x258
- Screen Resolution: 320x240
- Framerate: 30.000300
- Decoded Format: Planar 4:2:2 YUV full scale

On other similar videos with a different version of the codec, the uploading and conversion process is working and the result is playable on the browser:

- Type: Vídeo
- Codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1)
- Resolution: 320x258
- Screen Resolution: 320x240
- Framerate: 30
- Decoded Format: Planar 4:2:2 YUV

The code used to convert the video server side with PHP FFMPEG is this:

```
$video = $ffmpeg->open($path . '/' . $filename);
$video->filters()
         ->resize(new \FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension($destWidth, $destHeight))
         ->synchronize();
$video->save(new \FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264('libmp3lame'), $dest);
```

And on the browser is loaded with a video tag:

```
<video src="http://route/to/video.mp4" width="100%" height="auto" controls="" ></video>
```

Thanks

Comment: H.264 and AVC are different names for the same standard. Do you have samples?

Comment: Here (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B5RGV-5Gf9ZgZFdxS0JYQlQ1UzQ?usp=sharing) you have two folders. The "video que funciona" folder contains an example of a video that works perfectly. The "video niño colchoneta" folder contains 3 videos: 1.video 1: this doesn't work, 2. Video 1 conv: this video is the same that before but converted with VLC and this work perfectly. 3. video sphemory colchoneta: is an example of video converted and donwload from the our website. Thanks you in advance!

Comment: you shouldn't be using `AVI` as the video container format, it's not supported in most browsers. The second video works because it looks like an `MP4` with the wrong extension.